# JQuery Using passed parameter value to initialize a page via $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access or make a parameter value which was passed via an `<a>` visible within another javascript file. I can't figure out how to go about it.

I have the ff. line of code which goes to a new page: **student_learn_topiclink.php** everytime the link is clicked

```
var topicLink = $('<a>' + topicTitle+ '</a>').addClass('topic_link').attr('href','view/student_learn_topiclink.php?topicId=' + topicId).attr('target','_blank');
```

This is what shows in the address bar after clicking the **topicLink**

```
http://localhost/cai/view/student_learn_topiclink.php?topicId=5
```

I want to use the value **5** in `student_learn_topiclink page`'s JS file.

How can I expose or make the `topicId = 5` visible in `student_learn_topiclink` JS file?

In `student_learn_topiclink.js`, I'd like to do something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    alert(topicId);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters/979995) about retrieving URL parameters with javascript. For your specific example, try the following:

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var topicId = url.searchParams.get("topicId");
console.log(topicId);
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/craftman32/yxrvbcun/1/

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem and I can use this for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
var topicId = window.location.search.split('topicId=')[1];
console.log(topicId);
```